# mysql вывод из 2-х таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы

```
**prefix_user**
-----user_id   -храниться ид пользователя
-----user_profile_name  - фио пользователя

**prefix_user_field_value**
-----user_id -ид пользователя   
-----field_id   ид field
-----value - от сюда надо взять value=1
```

Делаю запрос

```
if(!isset($_GET['prefix_user_field']))
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, value FROM prefix_user_field_value WHERE field_id=1");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
    echo "<b>".$myrow['user_id']."--".$myrow['value']."<br>"; 

}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
```

Он выводит

```
user_id    value
54---------4484
262--------4528
257--------4498
278--------4510
51---------4475
53---------4518
```

А как сделать, чтобы вместо `user_id` он выводил данные `user_profile_name` (то бишь ФИО)?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать JOIN для связки таблиц

```
SELECT u.user_profile_name, p.value 
FROM prefix_user u
JOIN prefix_user_field_value p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE p.field_id=1
```

Comment: а можно полностью код, а то что то совсем мозг вскипел((

Comment: так? 
//ВЫВОД 
if(!isset($_GET['prefix_user_field']))
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT u.user_profile_name, p.value 
FROM prefix_user u
JOIN prefix_user_field_value p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE p.field_id=1");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
    echo "<b>".$myrow['user_id']."--"."<b>".$myrow['user_profile_name']."--".$myrow['value']."<br>"; 

}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
//ВЫВОД

Comment: только почемуто по 2 записи подряд выводит, дублими

Comment: При данной схеме и подобном запросе по идее подобных проблем быть не должно.

Comment: проблему так и не решил((

Comment: @ZOymyng, попробуйте использовать в запросе DISTINCT, он должен убрать дубли. Может у Вас там немного другая структура или присутствуют связи много ко многим?

Comment: DISTINCT убрал пустые поля тока,  сама структура таблицы с движка livestreet

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий запрос MySQL:

```
SELECT u.user_profile_name, p.value 
FROM prefix_user u
JOIN prefix_user_field_value p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE p.field_id=1
```

если есть дубли, то:

```
SELECT u.user_profile_name, p.value 
FROM prefix_user u
JOIN prefix_user_field_value p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE p.field_id=1
GROUP BY u.id
```

В последнем случае советую перепроверить, почему у Вас есть дубли данных по каким-то из записей.

Comment: Всё равно дубли( а в последнем запросе вообще , не чего не показывает